# Convert PDF to HTML without losing any format

Tags: python, html, pdf, heroku, pdf2htmlex

I'm developing a Python Flask webapp and I'm trying to convert some user uploaded pdfs to nicely formatted HTML, like the HTML that is being produced when you display a pdf inside an `iframe`.

I tried several things so far:

- the `pdfminer.six` library, produced messy HTML,
- trying to grab the produced HTML, when rendering a PDF with pdf.js, which is apparently hidden in a [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) with no access to its inner HTML
- finally I came across `pdf2htmlEX` (https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX) which produced exactly what I wanted.

Locally, this solution worked great, however in the production state (Heroku) I was unable to install it correctly. The project is deprecated and the documentation is limited and terrible. The problem has something to do with broken dependencies.

So, how to convert PDFs to HTML effectively without losing any format using Python or any other tool?

Thanks a lots.

*if anyone is willing to help me getting the `pdf2htmlEX` to work on heroku, leave a comment and I will post more details in a different post*

Comment: Give the user the ability to highlight, edit, and change the format of his pdf's through the web. Basically run JavaScript code on the actual pdf.

Comment: A highlight is relatively simple. What do you mean, **exactly**, by edit and change?

Comment: Change fonts, background color, text colors etc. Also, simplify the pdf by using something similar to arc90's readability project. I really need to convert it to HTML to have that flexibility. Which I finally got it to work, using Docker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be trivial. But I'll give some pointers.

You need an `app.json` in which you define your buildpacks.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#buildpacks

If [this project](https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX) is available via `apt` it's going to be easy. You just use the [Heroku's Apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) define an `Aptfile` that says which packages it needs to install. [Example](https://github.com/NNTin/shell-kun)
Then it installs it automatically and you are done.

If it is not available as a package you will need to create your own buildpack.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api
[Example](https://github.com/NNTin/heroku-buildpack-calibre) used [here](https://github.com/dipu-bd/lightnovel-crawler/blob/master/app.json).

Another solution is to dockerize your project and execute it as a docker container.

Comment: I already have the Aptfile method, but since it cannot install all the dependencies for me, I have to manually add a link (because most of them are deprecated as well) of the .deb file. For the past couple of hours or so, I'm updating the Aptfile, push to heroku and see what library is missing when running the `pdf2htmlEX` command, find that library and repeat. Tomorrow I'll look into this: "dockerize your project and execute it as a docker container". Thanks for your input @tin-nguyen

Comment: Heroku stack is based on Ubuntu 18.04 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack You can temporary deploy a virtual server with Ubuntu 18.04 and try to manually get it running there. Then retrace your steps and try to automate it. https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Building is useful. You might need a postdeploy to build see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#scripts You can solve the issue via `Aptfile` or a custom buildpack. It's up to you. Docker is possible but you'd have to implement the same build logic in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I made it work using Docker! Amazing application, great documentation and easy to use. Thanks a lot, I was really stuck into this one!